# GeoServer WFS 2.0.0 Default CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wfs, getcapabilities, default

I'm trying to retrieve DefaultCRS for one layers from WFS 2.0.0.

For the moment, only way I find is to use `GetCapabilities` and reduce the xml file by setting the sections like that :

`https://wxs.ign.fr/environnement/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SECTIONS=FeatureTypeList`

Is there a way to directly ask metadata for only one layer?

I also tried CSW but it wasn't conclusive.

---

Respond to @nmtoken comment.

I tried both method.

Set count = 1 to GetFeature is a double edge sword because for some ressources features are quite simple and the response time is fast but sometime features are quite complexe and loading the geometry takes more time than call **GetCapabilities**.

**GetPropertyValue** only list possible value for attribute but there are no columns corresponding to CRS. However, when setting `valueReference=the_geom` the third node of [xml response](https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetPropertyValue&typeNames=LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST%3Acommune&valueReference=the_geom&count=1) contain CRS.

Normally, the [argument **valueReference** can handle XPath() expression](https://3dcitydb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wfs/functionality/get-property-value.html) so I can select the third node attributs after url encoding with something like : `valueReference=the_geom/wfs:member/LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST:the_geom/gml:MultiSurface` or more simply with `valueReference=the_geom[3]`

In both case it's not working in my example :

```
# First try
https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetPropertyValue&typeNames=LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST%3Acommune&valueReference=valueReference=the_geom%2Fwfs%3Amember%2FLIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST%3Athe_geom%2Fgml%3AMultiSurface&count=1&outputFormat=gml32

# Second try
https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetPropertyValue&typeNames=LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST%3Acommune&valueReference=the_geom%5B3%5D&count=1&outputFormat=gml32
```

If anyone already used **valueReference** with XPath expression can you check if mine are correct ?

Comment: getCapabilities is the "correct" (and I suspect only) way of getting information about the layers of a service.

Comment: If you know the Feature Type (layer)  name then you could try a GetFeature request with count of 1, and restrict information returned by filtering by properties.  Or possibly you could use a GetPropertyValue request